# Query to find a count of multiplications in a table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using sqlite3. I have a simple task to do and for that I have to write a sql query which can be run in sqlite3. Please refer the below figure for my sample data, expected output and query necessity.

Somebody told me a hint to use "group by" but I know very little about SQL.

[image]

Comment: Where does these numbers `3*1 + 2*9 + 4*0 ...` come from? please explain?

Comment: these number are corresponding "count" column values for "term" which are common in both 111 and 222

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT sum(t)
FROM
  (SELECT f1.count*f2.count t
   FROM fruits f1, 
        fruits f2
   WHERE f1.term=f2.term
     AND f1.docID=111
     AND f2.docID=222);
```

The inner query multiplies the `count` of same `term` from `docID = 111` and `docID = 222`. The outer query sums all of them.

**UPDATE** : As pointed out by **ypercube**, this can be done without the derived table like this..

```
SELECT SUM(f1.count*f2.count) total
   FROM fruits f1, 
        fruits f2
   WHERE f1.term=f2.term
     AND f1.docID=111
     AND f2.docID=222);
```

Comment: from where we get the tbl1?

Comment: @vidit: What is "tb11"? Was that supposed to be "fruits"?

Comment: Correct but you don't need the derived table at all. `SELECT SUM(f1.count*f2.count) AS sumt FROM ...` would work. And I see no reason to avoid the `JOIN` keyword.

Comment: @ypercube- You are right, I'm still learning and sometimes come up with such in-elegant solutions. I have updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a solution with all the intermediate steps whilst working it out:**

First, find all the fruits with docID 111:

```sql
SELECT term, count FROM fruits
WHERE docID = 111;
```

Then find all the fruits with docID 222:

```
SELECT term, count FROM fruits
WHERE docID = 222;
```

Join them together on term. This is a conceptual leap, in that you must see the original query above as a single set, and then join the two sets together:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT term, count FROM fruits
      WHERE docID = 111) as f1
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT term, count FROM fruits
      WHERE docID = 222) as f2
    ON f1.term = f2.term;
```

Multiply the two "count" columns:

```
SELECT f1.count * f2.count as multicount
FROM (SELECT term, count FROM fruits
      WHERE docID = 111) as f1
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT term, count FROM fruits
      WHERE docID = 222) as f2
    ON f1.term = f2.term;
```

**Finally:**

Sum all of those columns together. Another conceptual leap, you wrap the entire query that you had before in a wrapper, and then do things to the results of that set, and which gives you a final solution:

```
SELECT sum(multicount) total
FROM (
    SELECT f1.count * f2.count as multicount
    FROM (SELECT term, count FROM fruits
          WHERE docID = 111) as f1
    INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT term, count FROM fruits
          WHERE docID = 222) as f2
        ON f1.term = f2.term;
) as all_fruits;
```

Try the code: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/aced0/2/0)

Comment: Thanks a lot jonathan. The answer is so explanatory even though I know 1% of SQL, I am able to understand. Can you advise me how I can modify this query when I need to take or all all docIDs in place of docID=111 and docID=222 remains same. Actually I need an output in columns in docID and result.